# Develop Rails app on Mac using with TextMate Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, textmate

I've found [this](http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html) a somewhat dated tutorial for developing a Rails application on Leopard with XCode. Wondering if anyone knows of a more up-to-date (ideally Mac based) tutorial that uses TextMate (or XCode if it's indeed preferred, or even just the command line).

TextMate is appealing to me but wondering how to work scrips like `ruby script/generate controller` etc. into workflow or if switching between command-line & TextMate is standard operating procedure...

If it matters we have Snow Leopard (10.6) clients and Leopard (10.5) OS X Servers at our disposal.

Thanks..

Comment: Switching between TextMate and command line is standard operating procedure for me and, I suspect, many other Rails developers on the Mac.

Comment: OK, but how to understand all the stuff under "Ruby" in the Bundle Editor?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with Greg, switching between Textmate and command line is the norm for me.

As for the stuff under the Ruby & Ruby on Rails bundles, most of those are small snippets for use while editing within various files in a Rails application, not really for generating files as you do with the script/generate command.